# How to populated C# listbox with string separated comma

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, desktop-application

I have a string that separated by comma like this:

```
"test1,test2,test3"
```

and i want to convert those string to list with folowing code :

```
    private void convertToList()
    {
        try{
            List<string> myList = occ.Split(',').ToList();
            listBox1.Items.Add(myList);
        }catch(Exception e){
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        
    }
```

I think that code will convert the string into a list and add it into a Listbox, instead, it shows only "collection"(yes only show the word "collection", nothing more) not the actual list.
why that's happened? can you tell me what's the right code?

Comment: `listBox1.Items.AddRange(occ.Split(','));`

Comment: It's because you add one item (List) not multiple strings as items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `Add` adds a *single* item which is a `List<string>` in your case. What should `ListBox` show for this? `Collection` seems to be a good enough solution. If you want to add *entire collection* in *one go*, try `AddRange`:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(occ.Split(','));
```

If you insist on `Add`, you have to *loop* in order to `Add` *each* `item` of the collection:

```
// To stop unwanted redrawing after each item addition
listBox1.BeginUpdate();

try {
  foreach (var item in occ.Split(','))
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
finally {
  listBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```